# Java: Enhanced for loop with unknown array size

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop

I am about 5 weeks into learning Java and am working on a homework assignment.  I have completed the requirements, but wanted to experiment with the program to make it more practical if it were really being used.

Our assignment is to create 5 different types of objects, store them in an array, and use an Enhanced for loop to process the array.  I am attempting to modify the program to allow the user to create between 1 - 100 different objects, store them in an array, and then use the enhanced for loop to process the array.

I started by creating an array large enough to hold up to 100 objects.

```
    Employee employees[] = new Employee[ 100 ];
```

The problem is if the user enters less than 100 objects, most of the array is empty.  The enhanced for loop attempts to process these empty spaces and throws an error.

```
    for ( Employee currentEmployee : employees ) 
    {
    ...........
    }
```

Is there a solution to this problem?  I want to allow the user to determine how many objects is created, save / reference those objects with an array, and process the array with an enhanced for loop.  Any way to do this?

Thanks,

Brent Crouch

Comment: A very easy solution would be to use an ArrayList instead of an array.

Comment: What is an "enhanced for loop"? Sounds like you want a data structure other than an array...

Comment: Enchanced for loop is just a syntactic sugar for iterating over iterables and arrays

Comment: @John3136 https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/using_enhanced_for_loops_with

Comment: @fvu Thanks for the link - been using 'em for years without knowing the name !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the other answers regarding the preferred use of lists rather than arrays or starting with an array of the right size, but if those are out of the question, you can also make your own approach work.

I don't believe the enhanced for loop chokes on the null values. You can easily filter them out yourself. Just do:

```
Employee employees[] = new Employee[100];
// fill the array
for (Employee currentEmployee : employees) {
    if (currentEmployee != null) {
        // process currentEmployee
    }
}
// or using continue to avoid undue nesting/indentation
for (Employee currentEmployee : employees) {
    if (currentEmployee == null)
        continue;
    // process currentEmployee
}
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the great responses.  Arend, I used your suggestion and it worked perfectly.  I'm a newbie programmer and I did not know that option existed.  I have already had the chance to use it in an unrelated program.  Thanks!

Comment: @Brent You're welcome. If you liked it, upvote the answer!

Comment: I tried, but since I only have a reputation score of 14, it will not let me.  As soon as I get to the required 15, I will come back and do that.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Brent Curious, I would have thought upvoting answers to your own questions is a basic capacity. Oh well...

Comment: Just earned the ability to up vote and did as promised.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just create an array of the **right** size :

```
Employee employees[] = new Employee[userInput];
```

Alternatively, if you don't want the user to specify the size, use a `List<Employee>` and populate it.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a Scanner variable to take an integer input from the user and use that to determine the size of the array.

```
  Scanner inputScan = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Enter number of objects");
  Employee employees[] = new Employee[inputScan.nextInt()];
```

Comment: Use square brackets for instantiating an array